# SRI for Google Sign-In

Tags: google-signin, subresource-integrity

I have a requirement for a site, I need to set the Subresource Integrity (https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) for the Google sign-in functionality, can someone tell me if it's feasible or if the resource (https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js) changes and I need to use any version mechanism or workaround in order to implement the SRI.

I've tried setting the hash generated in https://www.srihash.org/ and works fine but I don't know if this is going to continue working in the future:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" integrity="sha384-8BbIfH4u6uFaQg1wXFd+Bm1mY1i+Gkl485e4TAAaBp5kHTq8bueCRXIvnN82pmdZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you use this implementation?

Comment: not really, finally we addressed this as a constrain and deploy additional security solutions that checks if the pages changed

Comment: did it ever changed during all this years? My expectation - it is, and at the moment it changes, it will break a web site till new hash is deployed